# Django: How do you compare a QuerySet with fields on a ForeignKey object's property?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query a model against a field on a ForeignKey object's property.
I have the following models:

```
class Song(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  limit = models.IntegerField()


class Recording(models.Model):
  song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
    default=OPEN
  )
```

I would like to query Songs that have Recordings with status OPEN with a count of more than 'limit' (the field on Song). Looking over the [django aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) I tried something along the lines of:

```
# View

get(self):
  songs_count = Count('recording', filter=Q(recording__status='O'))
        songs = Song.objects.annotate(songs_count=songs_count)
        results = songs.filter(songs_count__gt=< each song.limit... >)
```

Can someone point the way on how to build this query?
I greatly appreciate any and all feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

Songs.objects.annotate(
    songs_count=Count('recording', filter=Q(recording__status='O'))
).filter(songs_count__gt=F('limit'))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. :)